# How to read database and table metadata from MS SQL server with minimum permissions

Tags: sql-server, metadata

I want to come up with the minimal set of queries that return the databases and tables in a Microsoft SQL Server instance, on as many versions of SQL Server as possible.

I'm not sure if I should half-answer my own question, but here's what I think I need for 2000 and 2005. Ideally I'd go back further, but I don't have access to older versions:

## Permissions

2005: a user with VIEW ANY DEFINITION permission

2000: a user the with public role on all databases to be retrieved

## Databases

```
sp_databases
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM sysdatabases
```

both work on SQL Server 2000 and 2005

## Tables

#### 2005

```
SELECT name FROM <database>.sys.tables
```

or

```
SELECT table_name FROM <database>.information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

#### 2000

```
SELECT name from <database>.dbo.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U'
```

Answer (score 2):

I belive INFORMATION_SCHEMA Views could help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Comment: You'll see I'm using INFORMATION_SCHEMA in one of my queries above -- however, in 2000, I don't seem to get any results with a user with just the public role, which is why I'm using dbo.sysobjects instead.